# how to do on demand update and delete on named windows esper

Tags: esper

How to perform on demand update and on demand delete on named windows in esper?

I followed esper documentation [link](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.3.0/esper-reference/html/nwtable.html#named_update_faf)
but i am getting error saying expected istream in update query.

ALso when i am trying to perform on demand delete the i am getting this error 
Incorrect syntax near 'delete' (a reserved keyword) [delete from StockEventWindow where  id =10 ]

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for "on update" in the EPL named window section of the docs.

```
create window MyWindow.win:time(30) as MyEvent;
insert into MyWindow select * from MyEvent;
on SomeEvent update MyWindow set thisField = thatField where someField = otherField;
```

Comment: what is SomeEvent here ?

Comment: I am getting this error -  Error executing statement: Invalid null or zero-element list of select clause expression types [on StockEventWindow update  StockEventWindow set price = 100 where price > 250  ]

Comment: Go to the tool at the following link: http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com. Next cut and paste this. create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double);
create window StockEventWindow.win:keepall() as StockTick;
on StockEventWindow abc update StockEventWindow set price = 100 where abc.price > 250;    // works for me